# how do i make a JPanel background that won't update?

Tags: java, swing, background, awt, screensaver

I'm trying to make an animated screensaver with some changing colors and moving shapes and I also want it to have a sort of trail effect (like how the most recent color on each pixel is continually drawn there if you don't set your background color). I achieved this effect once before, but I don't know how I did it. Currently the result is a moving square with that changes colors across a grey background.
ScreenSaver.java

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class ScreenSaver extends JPanel
{
    public static Component sc;
    public int delay = 1000/2;
    public int state = 0;
    public int re = 255;
    public int gr = 0;
    public int bl = 0;
    public int d = 1;
    ScreenSaver()
    {
        ActionListener counter = new ActionListener()
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
            {
                updateUI();
                repaint();
            }
        };
        new Timer(delay, counter).start();
        System.out.println("this is the secret screensaver that appears after 30 seconds of no mouse activity");//i have this line here so it doesn't print every time the screen updates
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        this.setBackground(null);
        if (state == 0)
        {
            gr++;
            if(gr == 255)
                state = 1;
        }
        if (state == 1)
        {
            re--;
            if(re == 0)
                state = 2;
        }
        if (state == 2)
        {
            bl++;
            if(bl == 255)
                state = 3;
        }
        if (state == 3)
        {
            gr--;
            if(gr == 0)
                state = 4;
        }
        if (state == 4)
        {
            re++;
            if(re == 255)
                state = 5;
        }
        if (state == 5)
        {
            bl--;
            if(bl == 0)
                state = 0;
        }
        g.setColor(new Color(re, gr, bl));
        d++;
        g.fillRect(d, 50, 50, 50);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        //ScreenSaver sc = new ScreenSaver();
    }
}
```

Main.java: (ScreenSaver.java is called as an object through this file)

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
//import java.util.Random;

//import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
//import javax.swing.Action;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionListener;

import javax.swing.Timer;

public class FinalProject extends JPanel implements MouseMotionListener
{
    public int delay = 1000/2;
    public boolean screenActive = true;
    public int why = 1;
    FinalProject()
    {
        ActionListener counter = new ActionListener()
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
            {
                updateUI();
                repaint();
            }
        };
        new Timer(delay, counter).start();
    }
    static JFrame jf = new JFrame();

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        this.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        if (screenActive)
        {
            why++;
        }
        if (why == 6)
        {
            why = 0;
            System.out.println("inactivity detected");
            screenActive = false;
            ScreenSaver sc = new ScreenSaver();
            jf.add(sc);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException
    {
        System.out.println("Welcome to Computer Simulator 0.1");
        System.out.println("this is the main screen");
        FinalProject e = new FinalProject();
        //ScreenSaver sc = new ScreenSaver();
        jf.setTitle("game");
        jf.setSize(500,500);
        //jf.setUndecorated(true);
        //jf.setBackground(new Color(1.0f,1.0f,1.0f,0.5f));
        jf.setVisible(true);
        jf.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        //jf.add(new ScreenSaver());
        jf.add(e);
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent MOUSE_MOVED)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: Do you get your desired effect if you override `repaint` to be an empty method and call `update` directly?

Comment: @DanArmstrong, don't try to call update() directly. Swing has a well defined painting hierarchy which you should not to override. For one thing this approach would remove the double buffering.

Comment: Exactly why I suggested it.  They seem to be wanting to hack Swing to get a non-standard effect.  But hacks / abuse aside, the answer below is the way to go with BufferedImages or redrawing items on paint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't invoke updateUI(). All you need is the `repaint()` to cause the component to repaint itself.

One way it to do the drawing to a BufferedImage and then use the BufferedImage to create an ImageIcon which you add to a JLabel.

The other way is to keep a list of object that you want to paint and then just iterate through the list each time the component is repainted.

Check out [Custom Painting Approches](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/08/custom-painting-approaches/) for working examples and an analysis of when you might use either approach.